# PGError: ERROR: aggregates not allowed in WHERE clause on a AR query of an object and its has_many objects

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, postgresql, activerecord, count

Running the following query on a has_many association.  Recommendations has_many Approvals.

I am running, rails 3 and PostgreSQL:

```
Recommendation.joins(:approvals).where('approvals.count = ?
                      AND recommendations.user_id = ?', 1, current_user.id)
```

This is returning the following error: https://gist.github.com/1541569

Comment: Can you clarify a few things? Do you actually have a column of the name `approvals.count`? And can you describe in free words what the query is supposed to do? Did you copy & paste the error message verbatim?

Comment: Could you try doing `Recommendation.joins(:approvals).where('approvals.count = ? AND recommendations.user_id = ?', 1, 1)` in the Rails console to try to isolate the problem?

Comment: MU: that query error'd the same way.  I do not have a column for count, but I thought Ruby had a .count function for arrays.  Is my problem that I don't have an array?

Comment: @TJSherrill: It looks like my assessment was corrrect to begin with. Move your `count` to the HAVING clause.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The error message tells you:

> aggregates not allowed in WHERE clause

[`count()`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/functions-aggregate.html) is an aggregate function. Use the [HAVING clause](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/sql-select.html) for that.
The query could look like this:

```
SELECT r.*
FROM   recommendations r
JOIN   approvals       a ON a.recommendation_id = r.id
WHERE  r.user_id = $current_user_id
GROUP  BY r.id
HAVING count(a.recommendation_id) = 1
```

With PostgreSQL 9.1 or later it is enough to `GROUP BY` the **primary key** of a table (presuming `recommendations.id` *is* the PK). In Postgres versions before 9.1 you had to include *all* columns of the `SELECT` list that are not aggregated in the `GROUP BY` list. With `recommendations.*` in the `SELECT` list, that would be every single column of the table.

I quote the [release notes of PostgreSQL 9.1](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/release-9-1.html#AEN110817):

> Allow non-[`GROUP BY`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/queries-table-expressions.html#QUERIES-GROUP) columns in the query target list when the primary
>   key is specified in the `GROUP BY` clause (Peter Eisentraut)

#### Simpler with a sub-select

Either way, this is simpler and faster, doing the same:

```
SELECT *
FROM   recommendations r
WHERE  user_id = $current_user_id
AND   (SELECT count(*)
       FROM   approvals
       WHERE  recommendation_id = r.id) = 1;
```

Avoid multiplying rows with a `JOIN` a priori, then you don't have to aggregate them back.

Comment: Can you direct me on how to modify the query based on this info, I am not solid with Postgres yet.

Comment: But there is no `count(*)` in the SQL (or `count()` on anything for that matter), just the rather suspicious looking `approvals.count` column.

Comment: @muistooshort: Well, you are right. A mixup of the name was also my theory in the first draft. But then, where does the error message come from? The table-qualified name `approvals.count` would not be mistaken for an aggregate function. I start to think we are not presented with the full story ...

Comment: We have the query and the error message (apparently) I can't think of any other possibility. The gist on Github does look like a Rails error message. Do you have an 8.3 installation kicking around? I only have a 9.0 accessible right now. I share your suspicion that something might be missing here.

Comment: @muistooshort: Sorry, only pg 8.4+. (How do you figure 8.3?) The whole story doesn't pan out. `approvals.count` wouldn't be mistaken for the built in aggregate function in any version of Postgres. Also, no brackets, so even a user-defined aggregate function  `approvals.count(..)` would not work that way. There is an unmatched bracket at the end of line 17 in the linked error msg, which made me think: "copy/paste artefacts?"

Comment: Sorry, new years.  I am a newb on this so I am sorry if I have not provided enough info.  My understanding was that ruby provides a count function on arrays.  I am simply trying to check where recommendation.approvals.count = 1.  I would be more than happy to give more info... just not sure what

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you have a column named `count` and PostgreSQL is interpreting that column name as the `count` aggregate function. Your SQL ends up like this:

```
SELECT "recommendations".*
FROM "recommendations"
INNER JOIN "approvals" ON "approvals"."recommendation_id" = "recommendations"."id"
WHERE (approvals.count = 1 AND recommendations.user_id = 1)
```

The error message specifically points at the `approvals.count`:

```
LINE 1: ...ecommendation_id" = "recommendations"."id" WHERE (approvals....
                                                             ^
```

I can't reproduce that error in my PostgreSQL (9.0) but maybe you're using a different version. Try double quoting that column name in your `where`:

```
Recommendation.joins(:approvals).where('approvals."count" = ? AND recommendations.user_id = ?', 1, current_user.id)
```

If that sorts things out then I'd recommend renaming your `approvals.count` column to something else so that you don't have to worry about it anymore.