# Why does this query need aggregate?

Tags: sql, postgresql, subquery, aggregate

I am trying to join 2 tables into one table `book` (they have one-to-one relation) and then nest a one-to-many relation `ebooks`

If I try to nest the one-to-many results it works fine:

```
select r.*, array_agg(e) e_books from gardner_record r
left join gardner_e_book_record e on r.ean_number = e.physical_edition_ean
group by r.id
```

This works as expected. I get the results back but there is a few more columns I need to add to `gardner_record` from another table with one-to-one relationship called `gardner_inventory_item`

This is what I have tried:

```
select book.*, array_agg(e) e_books from (
    select  r.*,
           i.price,
           i.discount,
           i.free_stock,
           i.report,
           i.report_date
    from gardner_record r
             inner join gardner_inventory_item i on r.ean_number = i.ean
    ) book
left join gardner_e_book_record e on book.ean_number = e.physical_edition_ean
group by book.id
```

But it doesn't work. The query gives error that `modified_date` (a column on `gardner_record`) needs to be in group by or aggregated.

Why is this? I make a single table in subquery. Then I left join the nested records as `ebooks` and use the `array_agg()` in `select`. Shouldn't that mean it is all aggregated?  It works in first query.

What am I missing conceptually here?

Comment: Please add sample data for your question.  It is difficult to to guess at what query you actually want/need here.  Note that the error message is just saying that you can't select non aggregate column when doing a `GROUP BY`.

Comment: Ok, but can you have a quick look at the update I made.  First query works fine calling the same column.  It only doesn't work when I try to join the other table

Comment: I thought the subquery would make it behave like a single table.  My understanding of your explanation means the first query that works wouldn't work so I am obviously not getting your meaning.  I am getting modified date on first query.  How does it know which one to get there?

Comment: You join on `ean_number` and then group by `id`? Is `ean_number` not `UNIQUE` also. Table definitions (`CREATE TABLE` statements) showing constraints would be instrumental, as always.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general any column that does not appear in an aggregate function must be included in the `GROUP BY` clause, however if the selected table has a primary key, then simply including the primary key in the `GROUP BY` clause allows all columns of that table to be selected without aggregation, which you make use of in the first query. However this approach [does not work when the primary key is wrapped in a subquery](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/88991/164193) since the Postgres optimizer cannot tell that the column was originally a primary key anymore.

To get around this, you could either list out all the columns of the `book` subquery explicitly (which might be cumbersome).

Alternatively, you could join and group the `gardner_record` and `gardner_e_book_record` tables in a subquery and then join the `gardner_inventory_item` afterwards. Basically just putting your first query as the subquery and then joining on the `gardner_inventory_item` table. Example:

```sql
select book_e_ebooks, i.* from (
        select r.*, array_agg(e) e_books from gardner_record r
        left join gardner_e_book_record e on r.ean_number = e.physical_edition_ean
        group by r.id
    ) book_e_ebooks
left join gardner_inventory_item i on book_e_ebooks.ean_number = i.ean;
```

But you really don't need a subquery at all:

```sql
select r.*, i.*, array_agg(e) e_books from gardner_record r
left join gardner_inventory_item i on r.ean_number = i.ean
left join gardner_e_book_record e on r.ean_number = e.physical_edition_ean
group by r.id, i.id
```

Comment: Thank you.  The way it changed behaviour rally confused me, you have explained it very nicely.

Answer (score 1):

The first query does not produce the same error because (I assume since you did not disclose) `id` is the `PRIMARY KEY` of `gardner_record`, and the PK covers all columns of the same table in the `GROUP BY` clause since Postgres 9.1. Related:

- [PGError: ERROR: aggregates not allowed in WHERE clause on a AR query of an object and its has_many objects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8684486/pgerror-error-aggregates-not-allowed-in-where-clause-on-a-ar-query-of-an-objec/8684512#8684512)

In the second query, you have formed the ***derived table*** `book` *before* you aggregate. In the outer `SELECT`, `id` no longer has that property (the derived table book has no PK) and it only covers itself in the `GROUP BY` list - and there are also additional columns from `gardner_inventory_item` which are not covered at all in the `GROUP BY` list.

This would work:

```
SELECT r.*
     , i.price
     , i.discount
     , i.free_stock
     , i.report
     , i.report_date
     , array_agg(e) AS e_books
FROM   gardner_record r
JOIN   gardner_inventory_item i ON r.ean_number = i.ean
LEFT   JOIN  gardner_e_book_record e
GROUP  BY r.id, i.ean;  -- Assuming these are PKs of each table
```

Or, **assuming** we can aggregate on `physical_edition_ean` just as well (since you mentioned that 1:1 relationship):

```
SELECT r.*
     , i.price
     , i.discount
     , i.free_stock
     , i.report
     , i.report_date
     , array_agg(e) AS e_books
FROM   gardner_record r
JOIN   gardner_inventory_item i ON r.ean_number = i.ean
LEFT   JOIN (
   SELECT physical_edition_ean, array_agg(e) AS e_books
   FROM   gardner_e_book_record e
   GROUP  BY 1
   ) e ON e.physical_edition_ean = r.ean_number
```

Simpler and faster.